# Simulation results of verilog in modelsim

Tags: verilog, modelsim

For my assignment, I need to take the results of my verilog simuation in modelsim in the log files. I have taken the screenshot of the waveform window. Apart from this I have also taken the print out of the transcript window.

Is there any way to store the transcript into log file?

Please explain the commands to store my results of verilog simulation.

Comment: Are you asking how to use system tasks `$display`, `$monitor`, `$fopen`, `$fdisplay`, `$fclose`, etc.?

Comment: Yes when I  use the tasks like $display output is written into the transcript window. I have taken the screenshot of the transcript window.Apart from this ,when i search on internet I see commands like -logfile <filename> | -l <filename>
(optional) Generates a log file of the compile.
-logfile <filename> — Saves transcript data to <filename>.But the command is not  working for me. I have created a file and specified the path but output is not being written to it. Please explain the ways to log my simulation results

Answer (score 2):

A .vcd file is an IEEE 1364-1995 standard file that contains all the simulation waveform information that is useful for debugging simulation. It contains all the signals in the design, so you do not need to rerun a simulation if you need to add a signal in the Waveform window.

To create a .vcd file:

1)    Compile and load design successfully in transcript window

2)    Specify VCD filename

- Syntax:    vcd  file .vcd

3)    Enable VCD to dump signals under a desired instance

- Syntax:    vcd add /*

Note:  This command does not dump signals of children instances

```
                  Enable VCD for encrypted instances will generate warnings
```

4)    Run simulation generate VCD database

5)    Quit simulation

- Syntax:    quit sim

To be able to display the signals in the .vcd file in Modelsim Waveform window:

```
  1)    Convert VCD to WLF format in ModelSim
```

- Syntax:    vcd2wlf

Note:  if the conversion fails, most of the time it is caused by non-existing instance path. Make sure the  desired instance paths specified in step 3 are correct

2)    Exit the current ModelSim session (needed for ModelSim for generate a proper VCD file)

3)    ModelSim session and open the WLF file created in the step 1

- File menu -> Open -> file2.wlf

4)    Select signals for debugging in Object window and add them to the Waveform window

answer is copy from
https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/knowledge-base/solutions/rd07062010_692.html